# How to efficiently list all files in an Azure blob using python?

Tags: python, azure

I need to list all files in an Azure blob using python. Currently I use the code below. this worked well when there were few files. But now I have a large number of files and the script runs more than an hour. The time-consuming part is the for loop. How can this be done faster?

```
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
import pandas as pd

connect_str = "************"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceCliaent.from_connection_string(connect_str)

blob_service_client.get_account_information()
c = blob_service_client.list_containers()

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("blobName")

l = []
for blob in container_client.list_blobs():
    l.append(blob.name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to achieve this using `list_blobs` method of `BlockBlobService`. After reproducing from my end, I have observed that the [list_blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.aio.ContainerClient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-aio-containerclient-list-blobs) method of `BlobServiceClient` returns all the properties of blob which is taking more time to proocess whereas `BlockBlobService` returns objects. Below is the code that was working for me.

```
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import datetime

ACCOUNT_NAME = "<YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME>"
CONTAINER_NAME = "<YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME>"
SAS_TOKEN='<YOUR_SAS_TOKEN>'

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME,account_key=None,sas_token=SAS_TOKEN)

# Lists All Blobs
l =[]
print("\nList blobs in the container")
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME)
for blob in generator:
    print("a"+str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    blobname=blob
    l.append(blob.name)
    
print(l)
    
print("b"+str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

*OUTPUT:*

[image]